# How to add wrapper on the word with space

Tags: javascript

In JS i need to add span as wrapper on the entire document text words.using below code i can able to add wrapper

```
function walk(root)
{
    if (root.nodeType == 3) // text node
    {
        doReplace(root);
        return;
    }
    var children = root.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0;i<children.length ;i++)
    {
        walk(children[i]);
    }
}

function doReplace(text)
{
    var start = counter;
    counter = counter+text.nodeValue.length;
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    var string = text.nodeValue;
    var len = string.trim();
    if(len.length == 0){
        return;
    }

    var nespan = string.replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g,function myFunction(match, contents, offset, s){
        var end  = start + contents.length; 
        var id = start+"_"+end;

        start = end;
        return "<span class='isparent' id='"+id+"'>"+contents+"</span>";

    });


    div.innerHTML = nespan;
    var parent = text.parentNode;
    var children = div.childNodes;
    for (var i = children.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        parent.insertBefore(children[i], text.nextSibling);
    }
    parent.removeChild(text);
}
```

using above code ill get below result

input :

Stackoverflow is good

out put:

```
<span>Stackoverflow</span> <span>is</span> <span>good</span>
```

expecting result:

```
<span>Stackoverflow </span><span>is </span><span>good</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add optional space character to your regex after the word but before the second word boundary: `\b(\w+\s*)\b`

Comment: You can change it to `\b(\w+\s*)\b` to support more then one space

Comment: how i can handle special character(__,?,',"",",. etc) as well?